# iOS HACClusterMapViewController annotation change

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkannotation

I'm using this mapkit library in a project I'm working on. I need to change around the position of the content of the annotation, however I can't seem to find where to make those changes. Does anyone have any insight into which method I need to modify to simply the annotation look/feel?

https://github.com/litoarias/HACClusterMapViewController

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are searching change the position on markers in HACClusterMapViewController?
For change position you need use the keys 'kLatitude' and 'kLongitude' and other keys explained in the official github page for using this Library https://github.com/litoarias/HACClusterMapViewController :

```
NSArray *dataForMap = @[@{kLatitude:@52.59758, kLongitude:@-1.93061, kTitle : @"Title 2", kSubtitle : @"Subtitle 2",  kIndex : @1}];
```

The keys are necessary for use this class!